# Changing Sql Server Column collation has no effect

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I am using a shared online Sql server database with a default server collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   and also the my Database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
I don't have the permission to change their collation.
I can only change the column collation. I changed the column to Arabic_CI_AI, which is nvarchar(100).
The problem is when inserting values using "insert into table1 values('اختبار')" the values are inserted as garbage ?????.
I don't want to use the prefix N' (N'اختبار') for inserting data.
My question is why the column collation has no effect.
Thanks

Comment: String literals are always interpreted in the collation of the database, so the string is already unrepresentable before it gets stored. Using Unicode strings really is the best option in this case.

Comment: "I don't want to use the prefix N" - and I want a Ferrari. But we don't always get what we want, and the right way to insert `nvarchar` data without it being broken before it even gets *near* the table is to use `N`.

Comment: if the database collation is set to Arabic_CI_AI, no need for the prefix N' to insert and retrieve data and the sql statement "insert into table1 values('اختبار')"  works just fine.

Comment: Indeed. But per your own question, you're not at liberty to change the DB collation. That leaves only `N`, or else using `NVARCHAR` parameters with clients passing Unicode strings to execute statements, rather than literals. If the column itself is `NVARCHAR`, the collation doesn't determine what can be stored (only the sorting and comparison rules).

Comment: Ok, now I got it, thank you all for answers